# Why is std::string_view faster than const char*?

Tags: c++, optimization, benchmarking, string-view

Or am I measuring something else?

In this code I have a stack of tags (`integers`). Each tag has a string representation (`const char*` or `std::string_view`).
In the loop stack values are converted to the corresponding string values. Those values are appended to a preallocated string or assigned to an array element.

The results show that the version with `std::string_view` is slightly faster than the version with `const char*`.

Code:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <stack>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum Tag : int { TAG_A, TAG_B, TAG_C, TAG_D, TAG_E, TAG_F };
    constexpr const char* tag_value[] = 
        { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF" };
    constexpr std::string_view tag_values[] =
        { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF" };

    const size_t iterations = 10000;
    std::stack<Tag> stack_tag;
    std::string out;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

    auto prepareForBecnhmark = [&stack_tag, &out](){
        for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; i++)
            stack_tag.push(static_cast<Tag>(i%6));
        out.clear();
        out.reserve(iterations*10);
    };

// Append to string
    prepareForBecnhmark();
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        out.append(tag_value[stack_tag.top()]);
        stack_tag.pop();
    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << out[100] << "append string const char* = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;

    prepareForBecnhmark();
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        out.append(tag_values[stack_tag.top()]);
        stack_tag.pop();
    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << out[100] << "append string string_view= " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;

// Add to array
    prepareForBecnhmark();
    std::array<const char*, iterations> cca;
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        cca[i] = tag_value[stack_tag.top()];
        stack_tag.pop();
    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "fill array const char* = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;

    prepareForBecnhmark();
    std::array<std::string_view, iterations> ccsv;
    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t i=0; i<iterations; i++) {
        ccsv[i] = tag_values[stack_tag.top()];
        stack_tag.pop();
    }
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "fill array string_view = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << ccsv[ccsv.size()-1] << cca[cca.size()-1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results on my machine are:

```
Aappend string const char* = 97[µs]
Aappend string string_view= 72[µs]
fill array const char* = 35[µs]
fill array string_view = 18[µs]
```

Godbolt compiler explorer url: https://godbolt.org/z/SMrevx

**UPD:** Results after more accurate benchmarking (500 runs 300000 iterations):

```
Caverage append string const char* = 2636[µs]
Caverage append string string_view= 2096[µs]
average fill array const char* = 526[µs]
average fill array string_view = 568[µs]
```

Godbolt url: https://godbolt.org/z/aU7zL_

So in the second case `const char*` is faster as expected. And the first case was explained in the answers.

Comment: From the disassembly it seems like the `const char*` variant calls strlen during runtime. I would think that the compiler can do this during compile time for `string_view`.

Comment: There's no reason to use `std::endl` here; you could make a `\n` part of the string you're printing anyway.  Printing is outside the timed regions so it should be fine for a flush to happen or not, but probably the cout / stdio buffer will be big enough that no flushing has to happen until the end, if the output is going to a pipe.  Not making a system call between each timed section is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply because with `std::string_view` you're passed the length and you don't have to insert a null char whenever you want a new string. `char*` has to search for the end *everytime* and if you want a substring you'll probably have to copy as you'll need a null char at the end of the substring.

Comment: What about becnhmark with array? Isn't it just a pointer copied to an array. Or does string literal it references is copied too?

Comment: I'd guess that the branch prediction/cache prediction units would also prefer it. Using a length, rather than a terminator allows the CPU to predict exactly how many fetches it needs to do. A terminator must be fetched, before you know it's a terminator.

Comment: @uni: do those numbers change if you benchmark the other one first?  Your total benchmark is over so quickly that the CPU might just be ramping up to max turbo around then.  Or the first array pays more in page-fault cost than the 2nd array.  TL:DR: that part of your results is probably down to naive microbenchmarking methodology.

Comment: Always try increasing the iteration count to see if it scales linearly, and/or do the tests in the other order to see if it's a quirk of warm-up effects.  Also, try slapping a repeat loop around the array usage to rewrite the same array many times.  (But then you risk having the stores optimized away, or other optimizations across iterations of the repeat loop.  So you have to check the asm to see that didn't happen, or if it did then use inline `asm` statements to defeat that optimization but still allow normal optimization to happen, because benchmarking unoptimized code is pointless)

Comment: @uni: or maybe it's real; I tried reversing them and running on Godbolt still shows fill array string_view = 19[µs], vs. 61[µs] for const char*.  https://godbolt.org/z/MyUxqE.  The loops loop basically equivalent, assuming they never fall through to the part that calls `operator delete`.  (Of course the string-view objects are 16 bytes wide and get copies with `movdqa` / `movaps`).  IDK, would have to try it locally with perf counters, or single step to see if delete calls happen.  Increasing iteration count reduces the difference ratio some: https://godbolt.org/z/jvM8Cr

Comment: @PeterCordes I followed your suggestion and increased iterations count and times benchmark runs to have time average across 500 runs. Here are results:

    iterations 10000 50000 100000 200000 300000
    string_view 17 87 183 368 588
    const char* 17 88 177 353 526
    delta  0 -1 6 15 62

In this case the difference is minuscule and `const char*` is now faster

Comment: @uni: That makes more sense.  Probably `const char*` is faster for large iteration counts because it's smaller, and those large sizes mean bigger arrays that start to get L1 or even L2 cache misses.  (Modern x86-64 can copy an 8-byte object just as fast as a 16-byte object, especially when they're aligned.)  Still not sure what was slowing down the small size without a repeat loop.

Answer (score 9):

`std::string_view` for practical purposes boils down to:

```
{
  const char* __data_;
  size_t __size_;
}
```

The standard actually specifies in sec. 24.4.2 that this is a pointer and size. It also specifies how certain operations work with string view. Most notably whenever you interact with `std::string` you will call the overload that also takes the size as input. Hence when you call append, this boils down to two different calls: `str.append(sv)` translates to `str.append(sv.data(), sv.size())`.

The significant difference is that you now **know the size** of the string after the `append`, which means you also know whether you will have to **reallocate** your internal buffer, and how big you have to make it. If you don't know the size up-front you could start copying, but `std::string` gives the **strong guarantee** for `append`, so for practical purposes most libraries **precompute the length in the `char*` overload**, although technically it would also be possible to just remember the old-size and erase everything after if you don't finish successfully (doubt anyone does that, although it might be a local optimization for strings since destruction is trivial).

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to string_view has the size of string value. The "const char*" hasn't information about size and has to define it.